# get dict data from dataframe column into new dataframe using dict keys as headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column is full of dicts:

```
                  Col
Index1   {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
Index2   {"A":4, "B":5, "C":6}
.
.
.
```

I would like a new dataframe as such:

```
          A    B    C
Index1    1    2    3 
Index2    4    5    6
.
.
.
```

As you can see, the dict keys in the DF column should become the new headers. Ideally I would like to preserve the indexes.

I have attempted to this using `from_dict` to create a new Dataframe from that column, but it is not working.

I.e.

```
new_DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(old_DF[Col])
```

And I am getting the error: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

I have tried other methods as well to no avail. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` with `pd.Series`:

```
>>> df['Col'].apply(pd.Series)
        A  B  C
Index1  1  2  3
Index2  4  5  6
>>>
```

Or use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['Col']).set_axis(df.index)
        A  B  C
Index1  1  2  3
Index2  4  5  6
>>>
```

Or try adding `tolist`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['Col'].tolist(), index=df.index)
        A  B  C
Index1  1  2  3
Index2  4  5  6
>>>
```

### Edit:

If your column is string type, try:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['Col'].map(literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

---

```
        A  B  C
Index1  1  2  3
Index2  4  5  6
```